# Is this a correct way of proving that $|A|<|P(A)|$ for infinite sets?

Tags: solution-verification

In this video on [PBS Infinite Series](https://youtu.be/TbeA1rhV0D0?t=379), they attempt to prove:
$$|A| < |\mathcal{P}(A)| \tag{1}$$
Where $A$ is a set (possibly infinite), $|A|$ is the cardinality of $A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the power set of A.

They use the following argument:

1. Show that $|A| \le |\mathcal{P}(A)|$ (this is not relevant to my question)
2. Show that there is a subset $B$ from $A$ that cannot be obtained by any bijection $G:A\to \mathcal{P}(A)$, thus $|A| \lt |\mathcal{P}(A)|$

To prove 2, they present a subset $B$

$$B = \{a\in A | a\not\in G(a)\} \tag{2}$$

They then show that $$\forall a \in A, G(a) \not= B \tag{3}$$

My objection is that $(3)$ does not prove $(1)$ because $B \not\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ unless $B = \emptyset$ in which case a bijection can map any element $a \in A$ to $B$.

Comment: I don't follow your 2.: there is no bijection from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$, and so every subset of $A$ has this property (vacuously).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown They are trying to prove "there is no bijection from $A$ to $P(A)$".

Comment: I rewrote your subset $B$ in set builder notation for clarity. Written in plain English it was fairly clunky.

Comment: Note: as lord shark the unkown said, the property holds vacuously as there is no bijection from $A$ to $P(A)$ (which is what we are trying to prove)     
But what they say is different - they say that for every function (or bijection, doesn't really matter) from $A$ to $P(A)$ we have some $B \subseteq A$ (and thus $B \in P(A)$ which is not covered. This is very different than saying that there is a fixed $B$ which cannot be obtained by any bijection, the order of quantifiers matter here. Note that if we replace the bijection with function in your definition the statement is false

Comment: @AsafRosemarin Can you show that $B \subset A$? (I don't see that at all, unless $B = \emptyset$ but then there is a bijection to obtain $B$).

Comment: you defined $B$ using the notation $$B:= \{a\in A| \varphi(a)\}$$ This immediately implies that every element in $B$ must be in $A$ or equivanlently, $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: @AsafRosemarin (That wasn't me, I quoted the "sentence" definition from the video but it was edited to the formula.) But still, the function is not even defined; there are no elements from A that will satisfy its definition.

Comment: But the function **is** defined. As I explained in my previous comment, you need to swap the order of quantifiers to get the statement "for every function $f: A \rightarrow P(A)$ there exists some $B \subseteq A$ such that $B \notin \text{Im}(f)$".  Now $B$ can (and should) be dependent of $f$, and as $B \subseteq A$, then by the definition of the power set $B \in P(A)$

Comment: @AsafRosemarin I edited the question to correct the definition of $B$ because it wasn't me who edited in that definition. Please see if you still think that $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: Fix the typo in $(1)$.

Comment: @RationalFragile My comment does not change... Every set that is defined as $B := \{a \in A | \varphi(a)\}$ for **whatever** predicate $\varphi$ must be in $P(A)$ by definition

Comment: @AsafRosemarin I understand. I'm sorry, I keep forgetting about the empty set being a subset of every other set. But my issue is that the argument sounds valid to me only if B contains an element of A but cannot be the output of G. In the case of an empty set, this is not true because G can map any element from A to P(A).

Comment: What they prove is that there does not exists any $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = B$ for our defined $B$. It is possible that $B = \emptyset$. In that case, there is no $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = \emptyset \in P(A)$. Note that the empty set is an element of $P(A)$ just like any other element. In any case, we get a set $B \in P(A)$ that is not "covered" by any $a \in A$, proving that $f$ is not surjective

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ consists of all elements of $A$ for which a certain assertion holds, $B\subset A$. In other words, $B\in\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: No. They don't show that $B  \subset A$. Just because you can formulate a sentence that involves elements in $A$ doesn't mean that it makes a valid set (e.g. the subset $C$).

Comment: The set $C$ is simply the empty set, which exists.

Comment: But the empty set can be mapped in an infinite set. Imagine a function $E$ such that $E(A) = A \cup \emptyset$. Let $A=\mathbb{N}$ and map $i$ to $i+1$ and $0$ to $\emptyset$. So showing that $B=\emptyset$ makes $B$ mapable by a bijection $G$.

Comment: I don't see why that matters. You asserted that the set $C$ doesn't exist, and I proved otherwise.

Comment: Wait, is $C$ actually the empty set? The empty set does not contain the element that the definition of $C$ says it contains.